# Awaiting code until filter is finished - Nextjs/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, next.js

I am looking on how to make my code after my filter function await the results of my filter function to complete before running. However I am not sure how to do this.

My filter function takes in another function (useLocalCompare) which causes the execution of my filter function to be a little longer than normal, which then leads to my next piece of code (that depends on the results of my filter function) executing before my filter function is complete.....which leads to undefined.

Is there anything similar to a callback I can use to force my subsequent piece of code to wait till the filter is finished?

Relevant code is written below.

```
if (flatarrayofvalues !== null && genre !== null) {
      const filtteredarray = await flatarrayofvalues.filter(
        (placeholder) => {
          if (useLocalCompare(genre, placeholder.name) == true) {
            console.log("HURAY!!!!", placeholder.id, placeholder.name);
            placeholder.name == placeholder.name;
          }
        }
      );
      console.log("MY FILTERED ARRAY IS", filtteredarray);
      console.log("The ID FOR MY MY FILERED ARRAY IS two ID", filtteredarray[0]?.id);
   return filtteredarray[0].id;
}
```

}
}

For those curious, useLocalCompare basically checks to see if the genre parameter pulled down from the URL is the same as a name parameter from the array I am filtering. Reason I have this is due to people having different case sensitivity when putting in URLS. EX: it will pull down "HORrOR" and match it to the object name in the array I am filtering called "horror". I then extract the ID from that object.

Comment: filter runs synchronously, btw what does `useLocalCompare` do ? and if it's a custom hook you should be calling at top level ...

Comment: ... and looks like `useLocalCompare` is synchronous, too.

Comment: useLocalCompare basically checks to see if the genre parameter pulled down from the URL is the same as a name parameter from the array I am filtering. Reason I have this is due to people having different case sensitivity when putting in URLS. EX: it will pull down "HORrOR" and match it to the object name in the array I am filtering called "horror". I then extract the ID from that object. That is why it cannot be called at the top level. However, should I convert it to a normal function instead of it being a custom useHook? @KcH What do you recommend?

Comment: Should I make it async @PA.?

Comment: I would name something else haha, so why is await at first place ? all those are just synchronous ...

Comment: @KcH was just trying different thing lol. the "await flatarrayofvalues" does not actually do anything.

Comment: when you remove `await`, does it work? if not, where in `useLocalCompare` is an async call?

Comment: from what you mentioned, both are sync... not sure what async things are going there actually ....  OH MY !! you have not returned anything from filter lol

Comment: @Time2learn didn't my answer work ... I'm curious lol :)

Comment: @KcH Yes, it did! I am curious though, when I put " return placeholder.name == placeholder.name" the word  return did not turn purple as it usually should in VS code. Instead it just remined light blue (same color as placeholder.name = placeholder.name). Do you know why that is? However, the return under it where I put "return false" has the return in its correct color (purple). What's the difference>?

Comment: @Time2learn not sure tbh

Answer (score 1):

you have to `return` the conditional from filter as it is "explicit return"

```
const filtteredarray = await flatarrayofvalues.filter(
    (placeholder) => {
      if (useLocalCompare(genre, placeholder.name) == true) {
        console.log("HURAY!!!!", placeholder.id, placeholder.name);
        return placeholder.name == placeholder.name;  // here
        // why not just return true ?? instead of above line
      }return false
    }
  );
```

Also I'm not sure this makes sense

`placeholder.name == placeholder.name;` you mean just `return true;` ?